# Is this sentence punctuated correctly?

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons

Is this correctly punctuated?

> He went to the bar to drown his sorrows; he is there now, probably drinking vodka.

Comment: Not yet. It has no full stop.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is correct, except that you have to add a point (.) after your sentence.

Your original sentence means that you know he is in the bar, but isn’t sure if he is drinking vodka.

But there are other possibilities.

For example:

> He went to the bar to drown his sorrows; he is there now probably, drinking vodka.

This sentence means that you don’t know if he is in the bar, however, if he is, he is drinking vodka.

Or you can add a coma after **there** in your original sentence, but it won’t make any changes in your sentence.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are unsuitable on ELU. And we always try to avoid comas.

Comment: Okay, then. @EdwinAshworth I was just trying to help :)

Comment: It's far more helpful for a new contributor to read and heed the advice given at the Help Center.

Comment: Sorry @EdwinAshworth

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean: “Is this sentence correctly punctuated?”.

There is one definite error: You need a full stop at the end.  “He is there now... “ is too separate an event to warrant the semi-colon.

One way to test is to read it out loud.  For me, there is a significant pause.

Many people disagree about the correct use of semi-colons.  however, my feeling is that your semi-colon should be a full stop.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are unsuitable on ELU.

Comment: Yes, of course, you are right. Sorry.